# Excel function to find the value based on one criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a database consisting of  two attributes: `NumId` & `Pro_Name`. There are several values in each attribute. I need to find a specific value from attribute `Pro_Name` based on `NumId`. Which function can I use?

I tried several function such as `dcount`, `countif`, `countifs`, but I dfon't think those are the right function to use for this problem.

Comment: Did you try `XLOOKUP()`? Post few sample data as text table.

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `VLookup()`? :-)

Comment: Can you further explain why you mention frequency in the title? (Preferably with sample data).

Answer (score 0):

Replace text between `[ ]` with the cell references. This formula will go where you want to pull in the Pro_Name.

`=xlookup( [NumID of same table], [NumID column of other table], [Pro_Name col of the other table], 0, 0)`

[More info on xlookups](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)

If you don't have the `xlookup` function you can use `vlookup` as well. Just make sure `NumId` is to the of `Pro_Name`.

`=vlookup( [NumID of same table], [entire second table, starting from NUMID col], 2,0)` this assumes Pro_Name is immediately next to NumId, 2 is just which column it is over from the first one. [Here's a support link talking about vlookups](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)